# Regex: match text from multiple lines only if a specific condition is met, ignoring other text inbetween

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
[Attribute Person]
name=John
description=This is a person
age=16

[Attribute Things]
name=Pencil\ndescription=This is an object

[Attribute Something]
name=John

[Attribute Animal]
name=Tom
description=Just a regular cat
age=2
```

I want to get the attribute name plus its description field ONLY if the attribute has a description field. From the text above I want to build a regex such that returns the following:

```
[Attribute Person] description=description=This is a person
[Attribute Things] description=description=This is an object
[Attribute Animal] description=Just a regular cat
```

Notice the attribute 'Something' is being ignored as it doesn't have the description field. Also, the description field of attribute 'Things' is inline with another field (note **the \n is intentional**).

So far I have:

`(((^\[Attribute \w+\])|((?<=\n)\[Attribute \w+\]))(?=[\n.*]))[\n\w\W]?|(description.*)`

but I it is including the attribute without the description (attribute 'Something')

I am trying to do this in python | pcre

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/bT8Mh9/1

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need the `ConfigParser`

```
import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('filename.ini')

print(config.get("Attribute Person", "description"))
print(config.get("Attribute Things", "description"))
print(config.get("Attribute Animal", "description"))
```

**Output:**

```
This is a person
This is an object
Just a regular cat
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)**

Comment: In Python 3 this is renamed to [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

Comment: @SimonShine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way if you want :

```
import re
string = """YOUR STRING GOES HERE"""
list_obj = re.find_all(r"Attribute(\s\w+)\]((\\n|\n)\w+\=\w+)?(\n|\\n)(description)\=(.+?)(\n|\\n)", string, flags = re.MULTILINE)
all_descriptions = filter(lambda x:x[5],list_obj)
print all_descriptions
```